# Add column in tbl_summary with mean (numeric variable) by rows

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am newish to R and would really appreciate your help on the following. I am making a table with the gtsummary package using the tbl_summary function:

```
install.packages("gtsummary")
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)
df <- mtcars %>% select(cyl, hp)
tbl_summary(df)
```

The resulting table shows n(%) for the cylinder groups (4, 6, 8) as well as Median(IQR) for hp. I do not have enough reputation points yet to embed an image, but here is the link to see the table: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whvz6.png

My question is: How do I add an *additional* column with the mean hp by row group (i.e., cylinder sublevel), instead of overall hp being included as a row? I have tried to add the customizable add_stat argument to tbl_summary but have not been able to get the desired result.

Please let me know if I need to clarify my question. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this. One way is to use the `add_stat()`.

```r
library(gtsummary)

fn_add_mean <- function(data, variable, ...) {
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(.data[[variable]]) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(.data[[variable]]) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(hp = mean(hp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    select(hp) %>%
    mutate(hp = style_sigfig(hp))
}
fn_add_mean(mtcars, "cyl")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   hp   
#>   <chr>
#> 1 83   
#> 2 122  
#> 3 209

tbl <-
  mtcars %>%
  select(hp, cyl, gear) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    include  = -hp,
    type = everything() ~ "categorical"
  ) %>%
  add_stat(
    all_categorical() ~ fn_add_mean,
    location = all_categorical() ~  "level"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(hp ~ "**Mean Horsepower**")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Daniel D. Sjoberg! One follow-up: if I wanted to add another row/ group, such as vs (in addition to cyl), what would I need to tweak? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Is this the type of table you're looking for? This function does two-way summaries of a continuous variable? http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/bstfun/reference/tbl_2way_summary.html Or do you want additional rows?

Comment: I have a table with many categorical variables (in rows) and I have the typical n(%) column but want to add a column with the mean of a continuous variable. So that I can see mean(x) stratified by each categorical variable sub-level, if that makes sense (I am probably not using the most accurate terms to describe this). Thank you!

Comment: OK, that is easier with `add_stat()`. I updated the post.

Comment: This is wonderful! Tweaking it some for my data and may have a follow-up question soon, but none for now. Thank you so much for your time and help.