# Add column in tbl_svysummary with mean (numeric variable) by rows (UPDATED)

Tags: r, gtsummary

I recently found [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68592878/add-column-in-tbl-summary-with-mean-numeric-variable-by-rows) on stackoverflow where they want to add a column with specific statistics for each row of the categorical variables in the data. I attached the code below:

```
library (gtsummary)

fn_add_mean <- function(data, variable, ...) {
  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(.data[[variable]]) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(.data[[variable]]) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(hp = mean(hp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    select(hp) %>%
    mutate(hp = style_sigfig(hp))
}
fn_add_mean(mtcars, "cyl")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   hp   
#>   <chr>
#> 1 83   
#> 2 122  
#> 3 209

tbl <-
  mtcars %>%
  select(hp, cyl, gear) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    include  = -hp,
    type = everything() ~ "categorical"
  ) %>%
  add_stat(
    all_categorical() ~ fn_add_mean,
    location = all_categorical() ~  "level"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(hp ~ "**Mean Horsepower**")
```

My question is: how could I modify this code to achieve the same but with a tbl_svysummary? is it possible?

attached is the code with the modifications I tried to test but I do not get the correct result as in the code proposed by Daniel Sjoberg (I don't know how to add results because the data is too big to share here, I apologize if this is a limitation to solve the problem):

```
fn_add_median <- function(data, variable, ...) {
  sampling_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, weights = ~wt, data = endes_data)

  data |>
    svyby(~v133, .data[[variable]], design = sampling_design, FUN = svyquantile, quantiles = 0.5) |> 
    rename(med_years = quantiles) |>
    pull(med_years) |> 
    select(med_years) |>
    mutate(med_years= style_sigfig(med_years))
}

survey::svydesign(id = ~1, data = as.data.frame(endes_data), weights = ~wt) |> 
  tbl_svysummary(by = education,
                 percent = "row",
                 digits = everything() ~ 1,
                 include = c(age_cat, resid_area, region),
                 statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}") |>
  bold_labels() |> 
  add_stat(fns = all_categorical() ~ fn_add_median,
           location = all_categorical() ~  "level")
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I think all you need to do is update the fn_add_mean() function to work with a survey object instead of a data frame (with the output structured the same way).

Comment: If you update your post with a minimal reproducible example, there is a better chance the community can help you with your issue. https://reprex.tidyverse.org/